# Change attributes order in woocommerce cart using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce to create an online custom cabinet door store for my company. We've had to use a couple of plugins to help calculate the many specifications needed to customize a cabinet door. But because multiple plugins are being used, the order in which the attributes are displayed are not how we would like it to appear on the cart. The product section of the cart table displays a description list  of  all of the product attributes in this order:

- Wood Type:
- Thickness of Door:
- Boring ($7.50):
- Unit:
- Specs - Distance 1:
- Specs - Distance 2:
- Width (in):
- Height (in):
- Total Area (sq. ft.):

HTML as it is displayed in the cart:

```
<dl class="variation">
<dt class="variation-WoodType">Wood Type:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-WoodType"><p>Mahogany</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-ThicknessofDoor">Thickness of Door:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-ThicknessofDoor"><p>3/4"</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Boringspanclasswoocommerce-Price-amountamountspanclasswoocommerce-Price-currencySymbol36span750span">Boring (<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#036;</span>7.50</span>):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Boringspanclasswoocommerce-Price-amountamountspanclasswoocommerce-Price-currencySymbol36span750span"><p>Yes</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Unit">Unit:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Unit"><p>Inches</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Specs-Distance1">Specs - Distance 1:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Specs-Distance1"><p>1</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Specs-Distance2">Specs - Distance 2:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Specs-Distance2"><p>2</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Widthin">Width (in):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Widthin"><p>13</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Heightin">Height (in):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Heightin"><p>18</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-TotalAreasqft">Total Area (sq. ft.):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-TotalAreasqft"><p>1.63</p></dd>
</dl>
```

And if "Boring" is not selected the cart will appear like this:

- Wood Type:
- Thickness of Door:
- Width (in):
- Height (in):
- Total Area (sq. ft.):

HTML:

```
<dl class="variation">
<dt class="variation-WoodType">Wood Type:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-WoodType"><p>Poplar</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-ThicknessofDoor">Thickness of Door:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-ThicknessofDoor"><p>3/4"</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Widthin">Width (in):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Widthin"><p>22</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-Heightin">Height (in):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-Heightin"><p>22</p></dd>
<dt class="variation-TotalAreasqft">Total Area (sq. ft.):</dt>
    <dd class="variation-TotalAreasqft"><p>3.36</p></dd>
</dl>
```

We want the 4 attributes associated with Boring (Boring, Unit, Specs-Distance 1:, Specs - Distance 2:) to be displayed underneath the Width, Height and Total Area.Like this:

- Wood Type:
- Thickness of Door:
- Width (in):
- Height (in):
- Total Area (sq. ft.):
- Boring ($7.50):
- Unit:
- Specs - Distance 1:
- Specs - Distance 2:

It seems a lot simpler to use jQuery rather than change the priority that each attribute is given to be displayed in the cart. I've used both the append() and the before() function to rearrange the list items for the  and  elements but the problem is if there is more than one item in the cart it puts elements from the other cart item into the first list. Here is my jQuery code to simply move the "Width" attribute before the "Unit" attribute as a test.

```
(function ($) {

   $('.variation dt.variation-Unit').before($('.variation dt.variation-Widthin'));
   $('.variation dd.variation-Unit').before($('.variation dd.variation-Widthin'));
}
})(jQuery);
```

This code takes all of the  and  elements with the class variation-Widthin and puts it before the first time 'variation-Unit' is shown on the cart. I've tried the each() and the result puts all the elements in each class twice so it appears doubled. If anyone could tell me what my code is missing so that only the elements are moved inside each cart item that it belongs to that would help a lot. Also if there's a better way to go about this I would love to hear you out.

Comment: check this [example](https://teckstack.com/wordpress-woocommerce-ajax-based-add-cart-variables)

Comment: When you tried `each()` did you each around the table row and then declare children? I've added an answer below that I think should solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are prefilled on the page and since they all have a unique class i.e. variation-WoodType, you could order the elements with flex in CSS.

If you are focusing on using jQuery as your comment says, I'd advise being more specific when declaring what elements to move. So do a `$.each` around each of the `tr` and then arrange the children contained. Something like the following, renaming `TABLE_ROW_CLASS` to the class of the row.

```
$('tr.TABLE_ROW_CLASS').each(function() { 
  $(this).find('dt.variation-Unit').before($(this).find('dt.variation-Widt‌​hin')); 
});
```

Edit: to find as per OP comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Although children() doesn't work because they're not direct children of the table row, using find() worked just how I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use insert before or insert after. For example.

```
<div class= "variation">
    <p class="paragraph1">1</p>
    <p class="paragraph2">2</p>
    <p class="paragraph3">3</p>
    <p class="paragraph4">4</p>
    <p class="paragraph5">5</p>
<div>

$(".paragraph5").each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).closest(".variation").find(".paragraph1").first());
})
```